# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. Powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

**Actually I wanted to extract values from log file and save it in csv file**

**This the log file**

Started : tue May 17 10:38:27 1990
Source : A:\Live
Dest : X:\Copy\Dest\
Files : **.*
Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:3
New Dir :         3 W:\Live
New File    :    100.0 m    randomfile.100M.xyz
0.0%

List item

0.0%
0.0%
,,,,
,,,,
100%

```
          Total      Remaining      copied       Extracted
```

Disc:      1            1              0          0
Files :         3         3              0         0
Name :      300.00 m   300.00 m        0         0
Times :   0:00:47   0:00:46            0:00:00   0:00:00

Speed :             1224242 Bytes/sec.
Speed :             3233.5920 MegaBytes/min.

Ended : tue May 11:39:15 1990

**I want to get it in below format**

started,source,Dest,speed,ended

tue May 17 10:38:27 1990, A:\Live, X:\Copy\Dest, 1224242 Bytes/sec,3233.5920 MegaBytes/min, tue May 11:39:15 19

**But I am get the output as below:**

Started","Source","Dest","Ended","Speed"

,"",,"Wed Mar 17 13","W"

"c","*.*","*.* /COPY",,"\Test"

,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,
"1         1         0         0         0         0","3         3         0         0         0         0"
"300.00 m  300.00 m         0         0         0         0","0","6703735 Bytes/sec.","383.590 MegaBytes/min.","tue May 11 39"

**Program**

```
Param($textlogfile = "Path")   

    $collection=@() 
    
    ###trim the white spaces lines from the structured text###
    
    $content = (gc $textlogfile ) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }   
    for($i=0;$i -lt $content.length;$i=$i+5)   
    {  
     $Started = $content[$i]  
    $started = $Started -split ":" |Select-Object -Index 1 |ForEach-Object Trim     
    $Source = $content[$i+1]  
    $Source = $Source -split ":" |Select-Object -Index 1 |ForEach-Object Trim  
    $Dest = $content[$i+2]  
    $Dest = $Dest -split ":" |Select-Object -Index 1 |ForEach-Object Trim  
    $Ended = $content[$i+3]  
    $Ended = $Ended -split ":" |Select-Object -Index 1 |ForEach-Object Trim  
    $Speed = $content[$i+4]  
    $Speed = $Speed -split ":" |Select-Object -Index 1 |ForEach-Object Trim  
    $coll = "" | select Started,Source,Dest,Ended,Speed  
    $coll.Started = $Started  
    $coll.Source = $Source  
    $coll.Dest = $Dest  
    $coll.Ended = $Ended  
    $coll.Speed = $Speed  
    $collection +=$coll   
    }  
    $collection | export-csv Path -notypeinformation
```

Could you please help me to get desired op
Please help me as I am new to using of powershell

Comment: What is `$content` here ? It seems that you dont have a value in `$Ended` and it is not able to split. However, first print the value of $Ended. Please Share [Minimal, Verifiable, Reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: add an check if $Ended is -eq $null

Comment: Please correctly format your code

Comment: Yes I tried using -eq $null but that's not working    -@Golden Lion

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is trying to invoke `Trim()` on the result of this expression: `(":")[1]`, believing it to be the right-hand operand of the `-split` operation.

Change the whole line to:

```
$Ended = $Ended -split ":" |Select-Object -Index 1 |ForEach-Object Trim
```

This way, no error occurs if `$Ended` doesn't have any `:`'s (you just end up with `$null` instead)

Comment: hi, I have edited the question could you please check

Comment: Please help me out as I am in need to get desired output